# Can HttpResponseMessage headers be removed?

Tags: azure-functions

My Azure function returns a HttpResponseMessage. It is possible to remove 
the headers from the response? Below doesn't seem to do the trick.

```
[FunctionName("HealthProbe")]
    public static async Task<HttpResponseMessage> Run([HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Anonymous, "get", "post", Route = null)]HttpRequestMessage req, TraceWriter log)
    {
        HttpResponseMessage response = new HttpResponseMessage
        {
            StatusCode = HttpStatusCode.OK,
            Content = new StringContent(DateTime.Now.ToShortTimeString()) 
        };
        response.Headers.Clear();
        response.Content.Headers.Clear();
        return response;
    }
```

Comment: Which header are you trying to remove?

Comment: @Mikhail All of them, except the response code ('200 OK' and those).